# Dynamically populating the value of a checkbox

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-mobile

i have a checkbox in my page.i have written javascript such that the attribute gets populated once the click happens in my page.I have to asign either true or false to the checkbox based on whether its checked or not.I dunno how to assign the value since its dynamically poulated

m poulating like this now i need true or false there in(#faxbox).How to acheive this

Comment: $("#faxpageyes").live("click",funtion(event){
jSonobject.checkbox=$("#faxcheckbox").val();
});

Comment: please put the whole code block

Comment: You have a typo in `funtion`.

Comment: .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() instead.

Comment: $("#faxpageyes").live("click",function(event){
jSonobject.checkbox=$("#faxcheckbox").val();
});
 i have coded jus this.I jus wanna send these to webservices>before i send this jSON object should be populated.

Comment: if($('#faxcheckbox').is(":checked")){
  set check="true"; }
 else {
   set check="false"; }
I dunno wer to insert this

Comment: Please put the whole code block in the post. It is pretty confusing. And please don't keep adding comments over comments. It adds to the confusion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you.

```
<input class="chkField" type="checkbox"   name="checkbox">

      $('.chkField').change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert('Checked');
       }
       else
       {
          alert('UnCheked');
       }
```